# C++ Builder 6 - how to change very old looking Widgets to Windows look?

Tags: c++, c++builder-6

I'm using C++ Builder 6 and f.e. Button or ProgressBar has very old look, like from Windows 95/98. :P

How can I change it? I actually want to make them like in Windows.

I mean make program in Builder and this program will show button in Windows 7 like it(button) looks in Windows 7, show ProgressBar in W10/W8 like it looks in W10/W8.
I want to make it depend on the OS.

I'm a beginner in C++ so please... make it really simple unless it is too hard.

Comment: _"How can I change it?"_ Get a more modern compiler, like VS2015.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That might not be necessary, there is a way to do it relating to manifest files. (Even programs compiled with MSVC 2010 have the old look)

Comment: See if any of the steps in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx can apply to you. (You might need to create a .rc file)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i wont, i hate it, literally. Maybe C++ Builder is not so modern, it is very old actually, but i like it and it's very easy for me. I don't fell good in VS or QT. immibis i will try, if someone have other things, come on.

Comment: @Persantarus _" i hate it, literally"_ Seems you fell down into some _"blinders syndrome"_. I'd never let my powers and capabilities be restricted by any particular 3rd party IDE, framework or such. You may prefer walking in  the _dark tunnels below_.

Comment: Easier is relative. Quite often I still fall back on a text editor from the early nineties because it easily does a few things everything else makes me jump through hoops to do. And as you may suspect, it absolutely sucks at a bunch of other things. Learn lots of tools and use the best tool for the job.

Comment: Immibis have you something easier than that? Or can u tell me what to do exactly? Actually i don't understand it.

Comment: I myself still use C++Builder 6 on a daily basis at my day job (the PTBs would not agree to upgrades through the years).  Yes, it is old, but it still gets the job done.

Comment: How can it be "too broad"? There's a good, clear, self-contained answer.

Answer (score 4):

C++Builder 6 predates XP and the [Visual Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773187.aspx) feature, so its VCL has no built-in support for theming/styling at all (there are 3rd party components for custom skinning, though).  That is why your UI looks "old".

Many of the native VCL components are based on standard Win32 controls that support Visual Styles if a [ComCtrl v6 manifest is added to your application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175.aspx).  However, several VCL components exhibit run-time problems when styled, since they were not designed to handle styling correctly.

Fortunately, you can install [SoftGems XP Theme Manager](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/controls/windows-xp-theme-manager) to address these issues (SoftGems' code was integrated directly into the VCL in a later C++Builder version).

SoftGems' `TThemeManager` component dynamically hooks into various VCL components at runtime (and also allows user-defined hooks for custom controls) to fix styling-related bugs in them.  Just drop it on your MainForm, and optionally set a few properties to control what type of UI controls it hooks.

SoftGems' `TXPManifest` component has an embedded ComCtrl v6 manifest resource to enable Visual Styles.  Just drop it on your MainForm, there is nothing to configure.

However, enabling Visual Styles is *all* that `TXPManifest` does.  An app can only have one manifest, and if you need to customize the manifest (such as for handling UAC, specifying Windows compatibility flags, etc - things which most modern apps pretty much need to do nowadays), don't use `TXPManifest` at all.  You will have to create your own custom manifest, compiled into a `.res` file that is linked into the resources of your application's `.exe` file.  The easiest way to do that is to define the manifest content in an external `.manifest` file and then compile it into a `.res` file using an `.rc` file, eg:

myapp.exe.manifest

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity
    version="1.0.0.0"
    processorArchitecture="*"
    name="CompanyName.ProductName.YourApplication"
    type="win32"
  />
  <description>Your application description here.</description>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
        type="win32"
        name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
        version="6.0.0.0"
        processorArchitecture="*"
        publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
        language="*"
      />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>

  <!-- other manifest elements as needed -->

</assembly>
```

mymanifest.rc:

```
#define APP_MANIFEST 1
#define RT_MANIFEST 24

APP_MANIFEST RT_MANIFEST "myapp.exe.manifest"
```

If you add the `.rc` file to your project, the `.manifest` file will be compiled and linked into the `.exe` automatically.  Otherwise, you will have to manually compile the `.rc` file into a `.res` file using C++Builder's command-line [brcc32 tool](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/BRCC32.EXE,_the_Resource_Compiler), and then you can add the resulting `.res` file to your project:

```
brcc32 mymanifest.rc
```

Otherwise, forget all of this and just use 3rd-party component suites that provide advanced UIs and functionality, such as [TMS](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/), [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/products/vcl/), [Raize](http://www.raize.com/DevTools/RzComps/Default.asp), etc.

Comment: Okay, thank you guys, it works! But i have one more question, it works when im in Builder and when im running .exe in project folder, but when i take .exe to another location(even with rc and manifest) it doesn't work. What should i do now?

Comment: @Persantarus it works fine (I've been doing it for years). Do you have your manifest compiled into the resources of your .exe file, with the correct resource ID and resource type? It sounds like you do not, or haven't done it correctly.

Comment: A guy told me that i should make .res file from this .rc file, but when i'm doing it by brcc32.exe it doesn't make .res file. I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Persantarus: netiher do we, as you have not provided *any* details about what you are actually doing. But in general, yes you need a `.res` file, and you need to link it into your `.exe` resources. If you add an `.rc` file to your project, it will automatically be compiled into a `.res` file and linked into the `.exe`. Otherwise, yes you can use `brcc32` manually to create a `.res`, and then add that to your project instead of `.rc`. If you are not getting a `.res` file from brcc32, you are not calling it correctly.

Comment: How should i call that in command line?

Comment: Did you read its documentation at all? Call it with the `/?` switch, or read the [online documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/BRCC32.EXE,_the_Resource_Compiler).

Comment: Ye, i was in this documentation, i'm doing exactly what i should do.

Comment: Ye, i was in this documentation, i'm doing exactly what i should do. //Edit: Ye, it works now! I had something bad in my rc file, now compiler works. I have only one more problem - can i do something with that rc and manifest files in .exe folder? Because .exe file works only with them, if there aren't manifest and rc, button look becomes old again. In addition i can't actually change name of this .exe file, because it doesn't  work either. Can I do something to compile all these files in Builder together, to have only .exe? I added .res

Comment: Using the steps I have given you, the manifest will be compiled into the `.exe` file, regardless of its name. Use a 3rd party resource viewer tool to verify that. If things are not working for you, you are not following the steps correctly. Either 1) the `.rc` is not defining the manifest resource correctly, 2) you are not compiling the `.rc` file into a `.res` file correctly, 2) you are not linking the `.res` file into the `.exe` file correctly, or 4) you are running the `.exe` file with the "Disable visual themes" option enabled in the "Compatibility" section of its right-click "Properties".

Comment: Oh my god.... we did it guys! :D Thank u so much for your help, i was adding it like File -> Open, i should do Project -> Add to Project... Thanks again! :)